# Bluetooth hardware is not detected after and upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, laptop, bluetooth, 15.10

I used to have windows on the same laptop and Bluetooth worked fine, but after Ubuntu 15.10 installation, it doesn't recognize the hardware, what can I do to get the proper driver?

This is my Hardware information on Acer R3 - 431 series.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 08)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

JEREMY THIS IS WHAT IT SHOWS:

```
kako@Eros:~$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b48a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:2093 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:1303 Apple, Inc. iPod Shuffle 4.Gen
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.134468] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   37.903594] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   37.903616] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   37.903620] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   37.903623] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   37.903629] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   54.402536] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   54.402540] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   54.402545] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1731.169854] Modules linked in: nvram msr ctr ccm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic bnep nls_iso8859_1 joydev acer_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm input_leds serio_raw uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media ath3k hid_multitouch btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth arc4 ath9k(OE) ath9k_common(OE) ath9k_hw(OE) ath(OE) mac80211(OE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211(OE) snd_hda_core snd_hwdep compat(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei_me i2c_designware_platform lpc_ich snd mei i2c_designware_core 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad soundcore shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport
[17378.566252] Modules linked in: hid_generic uas usb_storage nvram msr ctr ccm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic bnep nls_iso8859_1 joydev acer_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm input_leds serio_raw uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media ath3k hid_multitouch btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth arc4 ath9k(OE) ath9k_common(OE) ath9k_hw(OE) ath(OE) mac80211(OE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211(OE) snd_hda_core snd_hwdep compat(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei_me i2c_designware_platform lpc_ich snd mei i2c_designware_core 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad soundcore shpchp mac_hid
```

IT SHOWS THIS JEREMY :

kako@Eros:~$ dmesg | grep -i ath
[    5.769144] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[   37.121516] ath: phy0: WB335 2-ANT card detected
[   37.121520] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[   37.128273] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[   37.129392] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[   37.129394] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   37.129395] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   37.129397] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   37.129399] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   37.289182] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9565 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90000900000, irq=19
[   38.716405] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   41.571580] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1731.169854] Modules linked in: nvram msr ctr ccm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic bnep nls_iso8859_1 joydev acer_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm input_leds serio_raw uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media ath3k hid_multitouch btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth arc4 ath9k(OE) ath9k_common(OE) ath9k_hw(OE) ath(OE) mac80211(OE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211(OE) snd_hda_core snd_hwdep compat(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei_me i2c_designware_platform lpc_ich snd mei i2c_designware_core 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad soundcore shpchp mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport
[ 1731.169875]  autofs4 drbg ansi_cprng xts gf128mul algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq raid1 raid0 multipath linear dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci libahci r8169 drm mii video wmi i2c_hid hid sdhci_acpi sdhci
[ 1731.169901]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[ 1731.169904]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[ 1731.280714] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[17378.566252] Modules linked in: hid_generic uas usb_storage nvram msr ctr ccm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic bnep nls_iso8859_1 joydev acer_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm input_leds serio_raw uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media ath3k hid_multitouch btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth arc4 ath9k(OE) ath9k_common(OE) ath9k_hw(OE) ath(OE) mac80211(OE) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec cfg80211(OE) snd_hda_core snd_hwdep compat(OE) snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dw_dmac dw_dmac_core mei_me i2c_designware_platform lpc_ich snd mei i2c_designware_core 8250_dw spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad soundcore shpchp mac_hid
[17378.566301]  parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 drbg ansi_cprng xts gf128mul algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq raid1 raid0 multipath linear dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ahci libahci r8169 drm mii video wmi i2c_hid hid sdhci_acpi sdhci
[17378.566358]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[17378.566362]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[27197.016389] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[29852.810698] usbcore: deregistering interface driver ath3k

Comment: Please edit question to add results for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` thanks

Comment: I dont get what you trying to say :S !!

Comment: ok jeremy i got you here is what it shows

Comment: I hope you can help me with it :S !!! :(

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -i ath` show?

Comment: there it is @Jeremy31 , is it possible to fix it ?

Comment: I would try the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO as in 15.10 you have some other issue going on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33659/discussion-between-luis-carlos-carrasco-and-jeremy31).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminal, please type lspci  and paste the results so the community can help you with the specific driver. 
There is a chance that you may not have a compatible card, as it was in my case. I ended up ordering a compatible wifi/bt card for mine.

So it appears you have Qualcomm Atheros QCWB335, which has the bt and wireless coexisting on the same card. The good news is that your card is supported through the kernel using ath9k driver. The not so good part, but still good, is that to enable bt, you must manually enable the coexistence on the card. 
IF all is correct, and with any luck, running `modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1` in terminal will enable coexistence and get it running.

$$ How do i do that ? 
$$$ can you please explain me ?

*in terminal just type `modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1` and hit enter.

For more on kernel modules check this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules)

Comment: Please also identify the brand/model of laptop. This is a *Bluetooth driver* issue, not something specific to Ubuntu **15.10**.

Comment: i think i did, and that appears, is it compatible or no ?

Comment: oh the model of my lap top is an Acer R3 - 431 Series

Comment: Does wireless work on it or no?

Comment: yes wireless works fine :)

Comment: the comand modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1 is not working :( do i have to do something else before ??

Comment: sudo modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1

Comment: i did that before, but nothing happens :S it  :S

Comment: hmmmmmmm. I am now unsure.  Do you have a hardware combo to turn it on/off? suck as function+f3?